# Android-Query(AQuery) is used for SQLite Databse?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-query

I want to fetch data from my sqlite database using AQuery. But I don't have any idea about that. So, Is it possible to fetch data from database using AQuery?? If yes, then How ?

Comment: It depends a lot on what your server is setup like. Do you have *RESTful* commands to issue to the server? Also, consider using [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.com/droidQuery/), which provides a much cleaner approach to make such calls, and to handle success and error cases.

Answer (score 0):

AQuery is not designed for accessing local database. You can try some ORM, like Sprinkles or ORMLite.